# delayed job stopped working aftersome time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, delayed-job

I have a rails application and I am using delayed job for it. It was working fine but suddenly it stopped working.. I am not sure why it stopped working. When I checked in the db in the delayed_jobs table the get the following info in the table entries.

```
id: 1, priority: 0, attempts:0, 
handler: --- !ruby/object:DelayedReminderJob 
    attachment_ids: 
    - 19
    body: !str 
      str: |-
        <p>Hello Awad,</p>
        <p>Kindly reply to my mail..</p>
      "@_rails_html_safe": false
    message: 
    recipient_ids: 
    - 16
    school_id: 2
    sender_id: 3
    subject: !str 
      str: Pls reply
      "@_rails_html_safe": false
    last_error: 
    run_at : 2013-11-07 12:46:31
```

Please help

Comment: check on server if delayed job worker process is running. for linux server you can use "ps ax | grep delayed" command. if no process you will have to start it.

Comment: When I run the above command in the production server it shows as below.   17989 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto delayed

Comment: that means the delayed job process is not running you will have to start it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Rubyman.

check delayed job with below command

```
ps ax | grep delayed
```

if its working then it must show below lines

```
25274 ?        Sl     0:00 delayed_job                  
25280 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto delayed
```

if it shows below output then its not working

```
25152 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto delayed
```

you can use below three commands to start, restart and stop

```
 RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
 RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart
 RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
```

or simply you can check with below command

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status
```

output

```
delayed_job: running [pid 25274]
```

best luck.

Comment: For Rails 4: replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job